# Deleting a FuturePublished Message

Tags: easynetq

If I use `FuturePublish()` to schedule a message for future execution, is there anything in the EasyNetQ API to allow me to delete the message whilst it's sat dehydrated in the scheduler's SQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing available to do that I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Loving EasyNetQ at the moment, it does a lot of what I need and will be really useful in an upcoming project I'm working on this year!